# Suppress Trailing Comma Warning in VScode

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

[image]

Visual Studio Code Version: 1.56.2

Platform: MAC OS11 (Intel)

The default settings files (settings.json) has a trailing comma in it that causes warnings. This file is read-only and can not be accessed (from my research). I don't care if I can't fix it at this point, I'd settle for just suppressing the warnings if possible.

This question has been asked several times in various places in the last few years as this bug seems to be reoccurring. Being resolved and re-introduced in various releases (last introduced in V1.48.0 it appears), which at no point has anyone managed to develop an immediate solution.

After combing though the issue history and pull requests on the GitHub repo, it seems this issue has been addressed in the insiders build and in the OSS build of VScode but has yet to be rolled out into the production branch. Given that this bug is reoccurring and likely to be reintroduced in future releases… does anyone know how to possibly hack around this?

If you're curious to look into the reoccurrence of this issue further:
[https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=trailing+comma](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=trailing%20comma)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102061 suggests adding this to `settings.json`:

```json
"json.schemas": [{
    "fileMatch": ["foo.jsonc"],
    "schema": {
        "allowTrailingCommas": true
    }
}]
```

It didn't seem to work (anymore?), see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/202422.